# Setting the data context for a template defined by a package

Tags: javascript, meteor

Here's the relevant code template code:

```
<!-- display a list of users -->
<template name="available_user_list">
    <h2 class="cha_heading">Choose someone to chat with:</h2>
    <div class="row">
        {{#each users}}
            {{> available_user}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<!-- display an individual user -->
<template name="available_user">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="user_avatar">
            {{#if isMyUser _id}} 
            <div class="bg-success">
                {{> avatar user=this shape="circle"}}
                <div class="user_name">{{getUsername _id}} (YOU)</div>
            </div>
            {{else}}
            <a href="/chat/{{_id}}">
                {{> avatar user=this shape="circle"}}
                <div class="user_name">{{getUsername _id}}</div>
            </a>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="chat_page">
    <h2>Type in the box below to send a message!</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well well-lg">
            {{#each messages}}
                {{> chat_message}}
            {{/each}}
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form class="js-send-chat">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="chat" placeholder="type a message here...">
                <button class="btn btn-default">send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- simple template that displays a message -->
<template name="chat_message">
    <div class="chat-message">
    {{> avatar user=user size="small" shape="circle"}} <div class="chat-center">{{user}}: {{text}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and the template helpers:

```
Template.available_user_list.helpers({
  users:function(){
    return Meteor.users.find();
  }
})
Template.available_user.helpers({
  getUsername:function(userId){
    user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return user.username;
  }, 
  isMyUser:function(userId){
    if (userId == Meteor.userId()){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
})


Template.chat_page.helpers({
  messages:function(){
    var chat = Chats.findOne({_id:Session.get("chatId")});
    return chat.messages;
  }, 
  other_user:function(){
    return ""
  }, 

})

Template.chat_message.helpers({
  user: Meteor.user()
})
```

I'm making an website where users can log in and chat with each other. I've downloaded the utilities:avatar package to show the avatars of the users. The avatar image is based on the first initial of the username of the user. When I render the avatar template in the template `available_user` with the code `{{> avatar user=this shape="circle"}}`, it shows the initials in the avatars fine because it's with the context of the users collection.

I also want to show the avatar when a user sends a message but the template `chat_message` is within the data context of an array inside the chats collection. So it only shows the default avatar without the initial.

the [documentation for the package](https://atmospherejs.com/utilities/avatar) doesn't quite specify how I can set the template parameter for `user` or `userId`. Can someone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I included the user id into each object in the `messages` array under the field `userId` and in the template I set it as `{{> avatar userId=userId size="small" shape="circle"}}`